# svg button does not react to click

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, svg

I am building a simple app with Vue, Leaflet and Ionic. I have a centered cursor with a circular menu (built of SVG's) to start actions on a marker on the map. E.g. a menu that can be conetred on a marker and has 2 buttons: "delete" and "exit menu".
The "exit menu" button (lower right) works perfectly and the

> @click.prevent="exitBankje" is executed

, but the "delete" button (upper right) does not react to a mouse click. The

> @click.prevent="deleteBankje"

is not executed.

Hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

The Vue deleteBankje-component:

```
<template>
  <div style="z-index: 9999"
  >
    <div class="centermenu">
      <svg height="150" width="150">
        <line
          x1="75"
          y1="0"
          x2="75"
          y2="55"
          style="stroke: rgb(255, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2"
        />
        <line
          x1="75"
          y1="95"
          x2="75"
          y2="150"
          style="stroke: rgb(255, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2"
        />
        <line
          x1="0"
          y1="75"
          x2="55"
          y2="75"
          style="stroke: rgb(255, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2"
        />
        <line
          x1="95"
          y1="75"
          x2="150"
          y2="75"
          style="stroke: rgb(255, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>

    <div class="centermenu">
      <div style="transform: translate(85px,0px);">
        <a href="#" @click.prevent="deleteBankje" style="pointer-events: auto;">
          <svg height="75" width="75">
            <path
              d="M0 55 L0 0  A 65 65 0 0 1 65 65 L10 65z"
              style="
                fill: #4d4d4d;
                stroke: #000000;
                stroke-width: 0.55;
                stroke-linejoin: round;
                stroke-miterlimit: 4;
                stroke-dasharray: none;
                stroke-opacity: 1;
                paint-order: markers fill stroke;
                fill-opacity: 1;
                opacity: 0.5;
              "
              fill="none"
            />
          </svg>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img
      src="../assets/images/minus.png"
      width="40"
      height="40"
      class="centermenu ttr"
      @click.prevent="deleteBankje"
    />

    
<!-- Segment rechts onder -->
    <div class="centermenu">
      <div style="transform: translate(85px, 85px);">
        <a href="#" @click.prevent="exitBankje" style="pointer-events: auto;">
          <svg height="75" width="75">
            <path
              d="M 10 0 L65 0 A 65 65 0 0 1 0 65 L0 10z "
              style="
                fill: #4d4d4d;
                stroke: #000000;
                stroke-width: 0.55;
                stroke-linejoin: round;
                stroke-miterlimit: 4;
                stroke-dasharray: none;
                stroke-opacity: 1;
                paint-order: markers fill stroke;
                fill-opacity: 1;
                opacity: 0.5;
              "
              fill="none"
            />
          </svg>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img
      src="../assets/images/cross.png"
      width="40"
      height="40"
      class="centermenu tbr"
      @click.prevent="exitBankje"
    />

  </div>
  
</template>

<script>
import { eventHub } from "../main";


export default {


  methods: {
    deleteBankje() {
      console.log("DeleteBankje.vue: deleteBankje emitted");
      eventHub.emit("deleteBankje");
      eventHub.emit("endDelete");
    },

    exitBankje() {
      console.log("DeleteBankje.vue: endDelete emitted");
      eventHub.emit("endDelete");
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.centermenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -75px;
  margin-left: -75px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.ttr {
  pointer-events: auto;
  transform: scale(0.3, 0.3) translate(120px, -120px);
}


.tbr {
  pointer-events: auto;
  transform: scale(0.3, 0.3) translate(120px, 120px);
}

</style>
```

The app.Vue that calls the delete-bankje component:

```
<template>
  <ion-app>
    <ion-content style="height: 100%;width:100%;">
      <!-- <ion-router-outlet /> -->
      <front-page :bankjes="bankjes" v-if="dataReceived"></front-page>

      <menu-bar />
      <add-bankje v-if="showAddOverlay"></add-bankje>
      <delete-bankje v-if="showDeleteOverlay"></delete-bankje>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-app>
</template>

<script >
// import { IonApp, IonRouterOutlet } from '@ionic/vue';
import { IonApp, IonContent } from "@ionic/vue";
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import FrontPage from "./components/FrontPage";
import MenuBar from "./components/MenuBar.vue";
import AddBankje from "./components/AddBankje.vue";
import DeleteBankje from "./components/DeleteBankje.vue";
import { eventHub } from "./main";

const axios = require("axios");

export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  components: {
    IonApp,
    FrontPage,
    MenuBar,
    IonContent,
    AddBankje,
    DeleteBankje,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      bankjes: null,
      dataReceived: false,
      showAddOverlay: false,
      showDeleteOverlay: false,
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.refreshDataFromServer();
    eventHub.on("startAdd", this.startAdd);
    eventHub.on("endAdd", this.endAdd);
    eventHub.on("startDelete", this.startDelete);
    eventHub.on("endDelete", this.endDelete);
  },

  methods: {
    refreshDataFromServer() {
      axios.get("http://localhost:3000/bankjes").then((response) => {
        this.bankjes = response.data;
        this.dataReceived = true;
      });
    },

    startAdd() {
      console.log("App.vue: Hit eventhandler voor startAdd");
      this.showAddOverlay = true;
    },

    endAdd() {
      console.log("App.vue: Hit eventhandler voor endAdd");
      this.showAddOverlay = false;
    },

    startDelete() {
      console.log("App.vue: Hit eventhandler voor startDelete");
      this.showDeleteOverlay = true;
    },

    endDelete() {
      console.log("App.vue: Hit eventhandler voor EndDelete");
      this.showDeleteOverlay = false;
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Added later:
I found out that the DIV's around the menu items are about 150x75 pixels (in blue here):
[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell without a [mcve] (please update your question). But like @everton-costa, I suspect your elements are overlapping somehow.  Is there a reason why you have three separate SVGs for your menu?  Why not just combine them into a single SVG? I think you'll find things are a lot simpler that way.

Comment: I made an MRE and that really helped. Good suggestion.

Comment: I cannot use a single SVG as each menu item has a separate click handler and has to be a separate SVG+image.

Comment: When we say [mcve], we mean a minimal working example that you include in your question that we can run (or click through to) that demonstrates the problem.  Posting code is somewhat helpful, but not nearly as useful as an example we can run ourselves without having to do work to get it running.  Please create a Stack Snippet, Codepen, etc and update your question.

Answer (score 1):

A screenshot could help a lot... But in case you are using `style="z-index: 9999"`, make sure the templates are not over each other. For example:

```
<add-bankje v-if="showAddOverlay"></add-bankje>
<delete-bankje v-if="showDeleteOverlay"></delete-bankje>
```

Check this stack and try to change on the CSS classes the `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;` or flex.

Comment: I added a screenshot. I could make this menu work by removing the z-index and removing some redundant div's. I found out that a remaining problem was that the divs that have to surround the 2 menu items vannot be made smaller than 150x75 pixels. Due to this, the clickable area of the 2 menu items is bigger than the svg suggests. I tried all kind of changes but cannot make the divs the size I want: about 75x75 pixels.

Comment: It gets wore when I add a third menu item in the top left. The div of this menu item overlaps with the menu item in the top right. As a consequence the menu item in the top right is not clickable in the SVG-area.

Comment: Great @Hubert1957! Right now I suggest you to try to eliminate the grouped `DIVs` (keep only one with everything inside) and put the click on each `SVG` tag. For example: `<svg @click.prevent="deleteBankje" height="75" width="75">`.